# Existing DB column in Base 64 to AES 128

Tags: java, database, oracle, encryption, encoding

I wrote a java program and fetched columns in DB which is in base 64  encoded format and also i wrote AES 128 for New inputs

new data will be encrypt with AES 128.

**How to change existing old BASE 64 encoding colums in DB to AES 128 in simple way**

There are multiple tables in DB which has BASE 64 encoded columns

Comment: For CLOB check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3804279/base64-encoding-and-decoding-in-oracle/3806265#40852152, for BLOB check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42085147/can-i-store-binary-string-in-clob-column/42086105#42086105 After you decoded the BASE64 to clear text (or clear binary data) you can cipher it with [DBMS_CRYPTO](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_crypto.htm#BJFGFDFG)

Comment: Can you please tell me how can I change entire table columns in DB with single java program or with SQL 

There are multiple tables with encoded columns need to change in one program or query

Comment: You have to update each table with an UPDATE command.

Comment: What is the data type of your column? Which size does it have? Is the clear data plain TEXT or binary data? Do you want to store the AES encrypted data as BASE64 string or as raw binary value?