# How to insert a base 64 image into a BLOB column with Java? (Oracle)

Tags: java, sql, oracle, blob, blobstorage

I'm working in a project that fetches a base 64 image from an API, and I want to store it as an image (BLOB) in a Oracle table. This is what I tried to do, but of course it did not work:

```
// The real image64 String is around 40k of length
String image64 = "/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD......RzUUUBB2UtRREOFFFFpa//Z";

Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
stmt.executeQuery("INSERT INTO INFO (IMAGE) VALUES (TO_BLOB('"+image64+"'))");
```

The error I get is:

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01704 String literal too long
```

Now, I know that a way of going around that is to divide the String in chunks and inserting it like this:

```
INSERT INTO INFO (IMAGE) VALUES (TO_BLOB('"+chunk1+"') || (TO_BLOB('"+chunk2+"') || ...))
```

I tried to do that too. However, just like I commented in the first code snippet, the string is around 40k of length, so when I try to divide it in chunks of 4000 characters each, for some reason the command (which is really, really long) is not sent completely. It finishes abruptally, like if I overflowed the String type capacity or something.

This is what I send:

```
INSERT INTO INFO (IMAGE) VALUES (
TO_BLOB('/9jGOL5K...really long string...MdlNjgx45ouz')
|| TO_BLOB('U1hNR...really long string...95hcktXXLHV0uOW5tSQV')
|| TO_BLOB('RcB7Z...really long string...S6P4mGN3eXny6trpcI4X')
|| TO_BLOB('eOy4n...really long string...MrS06QOZ8Su2Tl8hjxH1')
|| TO_BLOB('7SNrA...really long string...TmyBzdiC2ye8drBNWaPi')
|| TO_BLOB('H1rnk...really long string...O5dqJ86r6bIxwxxf0bA3')
|| TO_BLOB('TxS0N...really long string...ZOT+7A9w+QVjZGvbqY15')
|| TO_BLOB('eHEiR...really long string...Lm3ECxuzQ9xdbiNtQBJ6')
|| TO_BLOB('o8Kjj...really long string...eDR1FqywLLlukprsXFk7')
|| TO_BLOB('ALzL/...really long string...PC6nmNf6Ip+vL4beqAF8')
)
```

And this is what the server gets (according to Navicat 11.0.8):

```
INSERT INTO INFO (IMAGE) VALUES (
    TO_BLOB('/9jGOL5K...really long string...MdlNjgx45ouz')
    || TO_BLOB('U1hNRwniiRW6rdyXZz8QSQulYBqYO95
```

As you can see, it barely made it to the second chunk. No wonder I get this error:

```
[Err] ORA-00933: command not properly ended
```

I really don't know how to handle this. I tried to do the same thing but with CLOB instead and nothing changes. Ideas? I know there is a BLOB type in  oracle.sql.BLOB package, but I didn't understand how to use it nor how to store it by reading the documentation.

Ideas?

Comment: It is normally not a good idea to store images in the database for reasons like this.  Considered doing the conversion in your own code and just insert the binary data from there?

Comment: Yeah, I saw something about converting it to binary but I don't know how to code that... The examples I saw weren't clear

Comment: Is you input data a BASE64 string or binary data? In order to convert CLOB/BASE64 string into BLOB and back, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42085147/can-i-store-binary-string-in-clob-column/42086105#42086105

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are trying to include the value in your sql statement.  That is never a good idea (as it causes security problems like SQL injection).  In order to do what you want, you need to use a `PreparedStatement`.  You construct your query using the "?" placeholder for the value, and then use the setters on the `PreparedStatement` to provide the actual value.  In your case, you would want to provide an `InputStream` containing the image data via `setBinaryStream()`.

```
InputStream imageStream = ...;
PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO INFO (IMAGE) VALUES (?)");
ps.setBinaryStream(1, imageStream);
ps.execute();
```

Comment: Can you send me a code example of this approach?

Comment: @ViníciusAbner there is a code example in my answer, as well as plenty of more detailed examples online, try googling "java insert blob into database"

Comment: @ViníciusAbner You may need to study more if the snippet given is not enough for you.  This is just the first of "interesting problems" you will meet when talking to databases.

Comment: When I posted the comment the code snippet wasn't showing. That's why I asked for an example