# How to convert Hex values to Base64 in Oracle?

Tags: oracle

I have the following string in Hex :

```
5B31E7C4931C2F62A4EB06573B3D4D4B7D96D2AAD05F9D626664CEB53023F1020F38B4399D98A2F280DC3606666B966A1B6878D2559044B2FC583FDFAB680714
```

I'm trying to convert it to **Base64** using Oracle.

According to this calculator : https://base64.guru/converter/encode/hex the result should be

```
WzHnxJMcL2Kk6wZXOz1NS32W0qrQX51iZmTOtTAj8QIPOLQ5nZii8oDcNgZma5ZqG2h40lWQRLL8WD/fq2gHFA==
```

which is correct.

I tried the following computation but it doesn't return the correct value:

```
UTL_ENCODE.BASE64_ENCODE(HEXTORAW(Value))
```

How can I achieve this in Oracle?

Comment: Note, `BASE64_ENCODE` works only up to 32k characters. If your Hex string could be longer then see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42085147/can-i-store-binary-string-in-clob-column/42086105#42086105 and/or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3804279/base64-encoding-and-decoding-in-oracle/3806265#40852152

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UTL_ENCODE.BASE64_ENCODE returns a RAW. You want to turn it back to a string

```
utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(UTL_ENCODE.BASE64_ENCODE('5B31E7C4931C2F62A4EB06573B3D4D4B7D96D2AAD05F9D626664CEB53023F1020F38B4399D98A2F280DC3606666B966A1B6878D2559044B2FC583FDFAB680714'))
```